# Why doesn't Ask Ubuntu's calendar match my calendar

Tags: discussion, support

My computer shows that it's still Monday the 19th, but Ask Ubuntu does not show me on site today, but shows me tomorrow.  Is there another setting I need to set on my computer?  I don't remember or see any time zone settings on my personal information page but my computer shows my location to be Los Angeles, which is the closest place on the time zone map.

[image: Ask Ubuntu Calendar]

My time settings on same screen shot.

[image: My time settings from the desktop]

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All dates and times on Ask Ubuntu are based on UTC or Zulu time (Can't remember which, though I think it's the latter). 7PM EST is when midnight on Ask Ubuntu occurs. Based on your screenshot I'm guessing you're a few hours behind EST, maybe PST so for you 4PM is when the "clock" on Ask Ubuntu rolls over.

Comment: Day-yum 86 days straight and I lose on a technicality.  Thanks and I will try again.

Comment: @lqlarry I know the feeling, I was at 97 days when I logged in at 7:20PM for the day, only to find that I missed the mark by 20 minutes :)

Comment: I found where to tell the StackExchange system time.  Hover your pointer over your user name and when the window pops up the system time (if this is the correct phrase) will be on the bottom left.

Answer (score 1):

I saw another question similar so I thought I would put a picture of it to help.  I never would have found it until Marco pointed me in the right direction.

Hover your mouse over your user name in the top center of your browser.  Look for the UTC time in the bottom left corner of the picture.  This is what the Stack Exchange uses for time and date.

I did this screenshot at 7:14pm Pacific time and askubuntu time shows 03:14.

[image: User window]

Edit out if not appropriate.