# When does askubuntu.com celebrate new years eve?

Tags: discussion, support

By my calendar, it's not January 2. 2012. When I look at the stats for this week, month, quarter and year, it seems we're still in December. When does this change? :)

Comment: [Related Question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2251/why-doesnt-ask-ubuntus-calendar-match-my-calendar)

Comment: See related question that Marco posted.  It shows you where to look.

Comment: Is *not* a typo for *now*?

Answer (score 6):

All dates in Stack Exchange are bases on UTC time. Check your local timezone for the offset from UTC time.