# Is it possible to Ask Ubuntu identify my GMT Time Zone?

Tags: feature-request, badges

I was interested in the [Fanatic Badge](https://meta.askubuntu.com/badges/53/fanatic) as I access Ask Ubuntu in a daily basis, so I started accessing it every single day. Although I live in Brazil, and my GMT is -3:00, and some days I can only access my computer at night, so when I go to Ask Ubuntu at 10 p.m. here at Brazil, it identifies that I am accessing it at 1 a.m. of the next day and it counts that in the previous day (or current??) I didn't accessed the site.

Today for example I got the day to be accessing Ask Ubuntu, so I did many votes and reach the limit of votes per day, and now, here in Brazil, it's 12:30 p.m. so the next day will turn in 11 hours, although as Ask Ubuntu doesn't consider GMT-3:00 it shows that I have to wait only 8 hours till the next day to have more votes. I benefit from this as time is reduced, although it's incorrect...

So did I miss some configuration to have my Time Zone considered or it is just impossible to configure?

If it can't be configured, can I ask for a feature to enable these kind of settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You, as well as the rest of us are accessing the same server set to UTC. See this [question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2251/why-doesnt-ask-ubuntus-calendar-match-my-calendar)

Comment: Thanks, I dind´t found that Q&A in my search, so is it possible to request a feature for this? For the site to identify my own GMT Time Zone?